# サービスアカウントでYouTubeへ動画をアップロードすることは可能？

Tags: youtube-data-api

利用者からOAuth認証は求めずに、サービスアカウントで、YouTubeDataAPIを使用し、あらかじめ定められたYouTubeのチャンネルへ動画をアップロードすることは可能でしょうか？

なお、Google Cloud Platformには、以下３種類の認証方法があるとのことです。

1. APIキー
   匿名ユーザーでAPIを利用する（APIの呼び出しのみをを許可してもらったイメージ）
2. OAuth 2.0 クライアント ID
   API呼出し前に、利用者に承認してもらったトークンを利用して、利用者のアカウントでAPIを実行する。
3. サービス アカウント
   OAuthによるユーザーの認証は不要。サービスアカウントに指定されているアカウントでAPIを実行する。

Pythonで動画をアップロードするサンプルは、2.のOAuthを利用しているものしかなく、都度利用者から認証を求める作りになっています。

[Googleのサンプルコード](https://developers.google.cn/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video?hl=ja.)

サービスアカウントでYouTube動画アップロードしているサンプル、参考サイト、書籍などありましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか？

以下は、独自にOAuth認証をサービスアカウントの認証に挿げ替えたコードと、実行結果を示します。

```py
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('colab-329402-XXXXXXXX.json')
service = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
# このサービスアカウントでは、YouTubeへ動画をアップロードできなかった。
```

以下は実行結果です。401 Unauthorized エラーが発生しました。

```py
$ python youtube_upload.py --file="./VID_20220423_185942.mp4" --title="Sample Movie" --description="This is a sample movie." --category="22" --privacyStatus="private"
auth_host_name / localhost
noauth_local_webserver / False
auth_host_port / [8080, 8090]
logging_level / ERROR
file / ./VID_20220423_185942.mp4
title / Sample Movie
description / This is a sample movie.
category / 22
keywords /
privacyStatus / private
Uploading file...
An HTTP error 401 occurred:
b'{\n  "error": {\n    "code": 401,\n    "message": "Unauthorized",\n    "errors": [\n      {\n        "message": "Unauthorized",\n        "domain": "youtube.header",\n        "reason": "youtubeSignupRequired",\n        "location": "Authorization",\n        "locationType": "header"\n      }\n    ]\n  }\n}\n'
```

Comment: 結論を自己回答としてはどうでしょう？参照先の記述内容も、要旨が判る程度に関連個所を引用しておけば他の人との情報共有に役立つでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。そうします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[YouTubeDataAPIのエラー](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors?hl=ja)
のyoutubeSignupRequired欄より、
「YouTube では Service Account はサポートされていない」ことが分かりました。
一旦、諦めます。ありがとうございました。